# Connecting two elements in the equation

Tags: equations

Suppose that my equation has six elements and I want to visually connect them into pairs (A with C, B with E and D with F).  Is that possible to do?  Example:

```
                ---------
                |       |
        --------+----   |
        |       |   |   |
    ----+----   |   |   |
    |   |   |   |   |   |
y = A + B + C + D + E + F
```

Comment: @Jubobs I agree.  There is a solution I need.  You can close the question.